# req.query for reading query parameter is not working in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I want to create a REST API using Next.js 13 and also want to filter and sort that API using a query parameter.

The API is created, and I can access it at `http://localhost:3000/api/portfolio`
but when I want to filter using query param with
`http://localhost:3000/api/portfolio?siteCategory=business`
then it is not working, showing all the data instead of showing only business category data:

screenshot1 - https://prnt.sc/y5-fvbOeFxNy
screenshot2 - https://prnt.sc/YTkUzYQNHvz0

What I am doing wrong? Why my API is not accepting query params? Any help will be appreciated.

```
import Portfolio from "@/models/portfolio"; //schema model
import connectDB from "@/utils/db";   // database connection
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export const GET = async (req) => {
 // connect with databse
  await connectDB();

  const PortfolioItems = await Portfolio.find(req.query);

  return NextResponse.json({ PortfolioItems });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers) shows, you would acces query parameters as below, using `searchParams` from the [`URL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) constructor:

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function GET(request) {
  const { searchParams } = new URL(request.url);
  const siteCategory = searchParams.get("siteCategory");
  console.log(siteCategory);
  return NextResponse.json({ message: "Hello World" });
}
```

This is how it's in the new `app` directory of Next.js.